# Database query doesn't return anything

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, dart

I'm trying to connect my flutter app to the database using the [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1) dart package. Everything seems right, I get no errors on the connection but I can't query my database. I'm not sure if my query reaches the database and is ignored or maybe I'm not reading the results right. I did as much debugging as my skills allow for and I'm out of ideas.

```
MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      user: 'root',
      password: 'Haffenstadt!',
      db: 'dbco'))
  .then((conn) {
conn.query('SELECT * FROM User').then((results) {
  print(results.isEmpty);
  print(List.from(results));
});
conn.close();
});
```

My console:

```
flutter: true
flutter: []
```

Comment: Why do you know that you get no errors if you no where check on errors?

Comment: @Thallius The IDE would inform me of any errors and I get no runtime errors. If I change the credentials I do get an error which makes me assume the connection is functioning.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because you close the connection before your query runs. Try calling the `close` method in `whenComplete`, like so: `conn.query(...).then(...).whenComplete(() { conn.close(); });`

Comment: @MichaelHorn Same results.

Comment: Same here. Not fetching even though conn is fine